# jQuery hide selected option in next select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

I want to hide the selected option in the first select box in the second one. My HTML.

```
<div>
<select class="fields-mapping">
    <option>Option1</option>
    <option>Option2</option>
    <option>Option3</option>
</select>
<select class="fields-mapping">
    <option>Option1</option>
    <option>Option2</option>
    <option>Option3</option>
</select>
```

I want option selected in the first select box to be hidden while opening second select box or vise verse using jQuery. What will be a good practice?

Is it something like this?

```
$('.fields-mapping').select(function () {
   $('option:selected', this).hide(); });
```

Comment: hiding an option?? you should rather hide the whole select element itself

Comment: I want hide/remove option. Like if option2 is selected in the first select box in the second select box there should not be option2. All options are same in select boxes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `filter()` function to find all `option` elements in other `select` elements with matching values, and hide them. Try this:

```
$('.fields-mapping').change(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    var $otherOptions = $('.fields-mapping').not(this).find('option').show();
    $otherOptions.filter(function() {
        return $(this).text() == value;
    }).hide();
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cp6bkxv8/)

Note this will work for any number of selects without any changes (so long as there are enough `option` elements within those `select` elements to make one choice from each).

Comment: Just curious about how it is achievable if we are using select2 plugin? Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to use the :contains and :not(:selected) selector.  This will enable you to find the selected option from the other select box.

```
$(".fields-mapping").change(function() {            
    var selectedOption = $('option:selected', this).text(); 
    $(".fields-mapping option:contains('" + selectedOption + "'):not(:selected)").hide();
});
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/28frmszv/1/

Comment: Just curious about how it is achievable if we are using select2 plugin? Any idea?

Comment: It is harder than I thought. I can't make it to hide by just using the .hide() method since select2 resets the styles of the generated li elements when the box is clicked.  What I did to make it hide is I use the disabled attribute and use CSS to hide the li elements with attribute [aria-disabled=true].

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/28frmszv/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can `.find` all childrens from all `select` but `not` the current select and to `filter` all options by current `text` and in the end you hide them.

```
$fieldMapping.not($this)
             .find('option')
             .filter(function () { 
                 return $(this).text() == text; 
             }).hide();
```

```js
var $fieldMapping = $('.fields-mapping');
$fieldMapping.change(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var text = $this.find('option:selected').text();
  $fieldMapping.not($this)
               .find('option')
               .filter(function () { 
                   return $(this).text() == text; 
                }).hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="fields-mapping">
    <option>Option1</option>
    <option>Option2</option>
    <option>Option3</option>
</select>
<select class="fields-mapping">
    <option>Option1</option>
    <option>Option2</option>
    <option>Option3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

change first box that will hide the option in second box
just try this following code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
first box
<select id="first" class="fields-mapping">
    <option value="Option1">Option1</option>
    <option value="Option2">Option2</option>
    <option value="Option3">Option3</option>
</select>
second box
<select id="second" class="fields-mapping">
    <option value="Option1">Option1</option>
    <option value="Option2">Option2</option>
    <option value="Option3">Option3</option>
</select>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $('.fields-mapping').change(function () {
       var currentId = $(this).attr('id');
       var currentSelectItem = $(this).val();
       if(currentId =='first'){
       $("#second option").css("display","block");
       $("#second option[value=" + currentSelectItem + "]").css("display","none");
       }
   });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```